# My Java Homework - 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Can someone please help me how to solve it?

Create a new class named blabla in the bla package. An instance of the class should 
be able to store a two-dimensional array of type double. The size of the array is not 
bound. The class should have a no-parameter procedure-like method named sortRows. The 
method should sort rows of the array in the following manner: the values of the last 
column must be in a descending order (greatest first, smallest last).

So i tried to do myself, please help me if there is a mistake.

```
  double temp = 0;

    double[][] number;

    boolean fixed=false;
    while(fixed==false){
        fixed=true;
    }
    number = new double[5][5];
    for(int i=0; i<number.length-1; i++){
        if(number[i][i] > number[i+1][i+1])

        temp = number[i+1][i+1];
        number[i+1][i+1] = number[i][i];
        number[i][i]=temp;
        fixed=false;
    }
            for(int i=0; i<number.length; i++){

    System.out.println(number[i][i]);
}
```

Comment: We'll be glad to help, but you need to ask a question letting us know where your stuck. Simply posting your assignment is not enough, and we're certainly not going to do your homework for you. So please put a little effort into improving your question, and you'll likely get good help.

Comment: How much will you pay me to do your homework? :D

Comment: His question is: "Will someone do my homework for me?"  The parameters of his assignment are clearly laid out for him, but he either doesn't understand or doesn't want to do his work.

Comment: actually i havent learned how to do it yet and have no idea.. already tried to solve myself but couldnt :/

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not gonna do your homework!

You should be able to create a class in a package yourself,
For creating dynamic arrays, check this topic: [Variable length (Dynamic) Arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426671/variable-length-dynamic-arrays-in-java)

For sorting arrays, check this topic: [char multidimensional array sorting in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851094/char-multidimensional-array-sorting-in-java)

This should get you going, I hope ;)